# Show ion-chip when I type in input

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, input

I hope you are well.

I have a problem with ion-chip and ion-input.

When user/someone is typing an email in ion-input I am trying to show the email as an ion-chip when the user/someone is pressing the keyup.Space (space). Basically the trigger to show the email as a ion-chip is when the user is pressing the keyup.Space after he typed the email.

What I have right now  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdcrqr?file=src%2Fapp%2F

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Something like this:

in your html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-chip *ngFor="let e of emails; let i = index;">
  <ion-label>{{e}}</ion-label>
  <ion-icon name="close-outline" (click)="removeItem(i)"></ion-icon>
</ion-chip>
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" (keyup.Space)= "doSomething(userEmail)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

.ts:

```
userEmail:any;
emails = [];

doSomething(email){
     if(this.doValidate(email)){
        this.emails.push(email);
        this.userEmail = '';  // reset ngModel it will clear old value
     }
}

removeItem(i){
     this.emails.splice(i, 1)
}



validateEmail(email) { //Validates the email address
    var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return emailRegex.test(email);
}

validatePhone(phone) { //Validates the phone number
    var phoneRegex = /^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/; // Change this regex based on requirement
    return phoneRegex.test(phone);
}

doValidate(email) {
   if (!validateEmail(email) || !validatePhone(email) ){
    alert("Invalid Email");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, its working but how can i define that the chip is an email or a phone number? for exemple if I ad gh@gmail.com the chip will be added but anything I write in the input and press Space will be added as well. How can I difine in the function that the chip has to be added only if its email format or phone format?

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot for your updated answer , its working as I can see but its still a problem and I would really appreciate if you can help me with this one too. When I type in the input email or number and press SPACE , the chip appear but the text that I put (the email) its staying as well there after the chip . For exemple if i write d@gmail.com the chip appear with that but i still got the email right next to the chip. How can I reset that value to not appear after the chip in the input ? If its not clear I can send a image or something . Looking forward for your answer , thanks a lot.

Comment: its working peerfectly , thank you so man , really appreciate all your help and work . I feel bad but I have 1 more question , if you can't help or dont have time its ok I just need 1 more step to complete my page. Right now the chip appears , the text after the chip its not appering now but when I type the email and the chip appear my list below its gone. I have connecting to the input a search with an Array of Objects with name and check property binded to ion-checkbox. I need now to display my original Array of objects even when the email chip appear.  Do you have any ideea how to do that?

Comment: Check documentation for `ion-searchbar` with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other alternatives instead of ion-chips.

You can use the material components to make it works.
Please refer the below code to get the context.

```
 <mat-chip-list #embeddedList class='tags-chip-list'>
              <mat-chip class='tag' *ngFor="let tag of field;let index=index;" [selectable]="true"
                [removable]="true" (removed)="removeEmbeddedField(index)">
                {{tag}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip>
              <input placeholder="Embedded Fields" #embeddedInput [matChipInputFor]="embeddedList"
                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="embeddedInput?.value ? [9, 13, 188] : []"
                [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="false" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addEmbeddedField($event)">
            </mat-chip-list>
```